# boxplot time series by monthly average in r

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series with hourly data on energy consumption in the form of a zoo object. And there are 16 indices (in the range [1:143206]) for which the Date is NA. Here is a sample of the data:

```
     Date                PJMW_MW
1    2002-04-01 01:00:00 4374
...
8709 2003-03-29 23:00:00 4827
8710 2003-03-30 00:00:00 4611
8711 2003-03-30 01:00:00 4421
8712 NA                  4285
8713 2003-03-30 03:00:00 4212
8714 2003-03-30 04:00:00 4321
...
143206 2018-08-03 00:00:005489
```

The data above is a data.frame object called `dat` but I have it in a zoo object called `hourly_ts`:

```
1    4374
...
7709 6135
7710 6324
7711 6626
7712 6866
7713 6987
7714 7028
7715 7026
...
143206 5265
```

I would like to see the monthly averages, like, for which month is the consumption generally higher, and I saw that there is a simple formula for this: `boxplot(hourly_ts ~ cycle(hourly_ts))`

But the error `Error in cycle.zoo(hourly_ts) : ‘x’is not regular` appears.

The weird thing is that `hourly_ts` has a specified frequency (24 hours per day) and start time (April 1st 2002 01:00:00), so from that there shouldn't be any missing values in the time.

Supposing the missing values are what's causing the irregularity, is there a way I can add the values myself?

I would also like to use the `aggregate` function but have no idea what the `by` parameter should be.

Comment: could  you provide a minimal data sample so the error could be reproduced?

Comment: 6 rows is too minimal?

Comment: do you get the same mistake with 6 rows?